# Actionscript 3 Simple Cookie

Tags: actionscript-3, cookies, actionscript, checkbox

I have a flash-based screen that includes a small checkbox indicating whether or not the user would like the screen to show up on future visits. The design is done, and now I just need some assistance with AS3 to make it functional.

The check box is using one of the built-in Flash components. If the box is checked, I'd like for the tutorial not to show up upon future visits.

Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance!

D

Comment: Check out my answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989445/save-load-state-as3-adobe-air/15995596#15995596   OR  this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667848/as3-for-ios-how-to-serialize-an-array-and-then-save-it/15668079#15668079

Comment: please consider doing some research ... post issues if you hit a bump and are stuck without further ideas...

Answer (score 0):

I think this (http://www.adobe.com/security/flashplayer/articles/lso/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I've read the information and it gave a good overview of what I'm looking for. At this point, I'm actually in search of more specific information on how to implement the above request. If you have any thoughts on the matter, I'd appreciate hearing them

Comment: can you post some code or provide more information of what you have done till now... in it's current state, the question seems quite vague...

Comment: I actually don't have any of the code formally written. I have the flash file laid out with the check box created as a component. Once the submit button is hit, I need the computer to remember not to show the screen on the user's future visits. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I did but didn't find what I was looking for. That's part of what led me here. In the end, it sounds like you're at the early limit of your desire to help. No worries

Comment: search for flash cs5 check box click... one of the first links should be Adobe help page for check boxes... i could paste the link myself, but an unable to copy link on my mobile browser...